# Why does my cat paw at his reflection in the mirror?

Tags: cats, behavior

Not every time he looks in the mirror, obviously, but sometimes my cat will sort of sit on his back legs and paw with his front on his reflection in the mirror? There doesn't seem to be much aggression towards it at all, just sort of lightly hitting it and then dragging his paws down it repeatedly. What's he doing?

Comment: He triws to figure out, why this beautiful cat in fron of him does not smell or make noises. If he has experience with windows he may connect it to this, another cat is sitting behind a glas. He tries to communicate with it I would assume

Comment: Your cat most likely thinks it is another cat and if he is a male cat then he will probably be very territorial and he will wan to know if there is really another cat in 'his' house.

Answer (score 1):

Cats don't recognise their own mirror image. Your cat thinks he's interacting with another cat that's just curious, and is curious himself.

Mine do the same, it's rather cute.

If your cat were a more aggressive one towards other cats, there'd be fighting with his own mirror image instead.